# Magento2 API directory purpose

Tags: magento2, api

When i look at **magento 2 core**, in some modules API directory is present and in some modules there is no **API directory**.

**API Directory** is used for **implementing Web services(SOAP,REST)** or it has other purpose too??

Comment: I think the most useful info is from here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Answer (score 1):

Api directory have repositories.
It Contains set of code that third-party developers can call, implement, or build as a plug-in. Magento guarantees that this code will not change in subsequent releases without a major version change.
Public interfaces for a module are marked with @api annotation.
In general, the purpose of a repository is to hide the storage related logic.
A client of a repository should not care whether the returned entity is held in memory, in an array, is retrieved from a MySQL database, fetched from a remote API or from a file.
Magento 2 repository methods can easily be exposed as API resources, making them valuable for integrations with third party systems or headless Magento instances.

UseFul Links : 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/api-concepts.html
http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/